# Find the relative maxima and minima of y by the second-derivative test

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, partial-derivative

Find the relative maxima and minima of y by the second-derivative test
$$y=−2x^2+8x+25$$

So far I've done:
$$
\begin{align}
f'(x)&=-4x+8 \\
f''(x)&=-4
\end {align}
$$

Then
$$
\begin{align}
f'(x)&=0 \\
-4x+8&=0 \\
x&=2
\end{align}
$$

Not sure what to do from here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At $x=2$, $f''(x)=-4$, which is negative, so $x=2$ is a maximum point

Comment: Thanks! Didn't realize it was that simple.